# Matching a dynamic array of rows to a dataset

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

So I have a large data set of products, (in my case, boxes of floor tiles).

each product has five related columns:

1. The product name ("Stone-Grey", "Cubic-Dark", etc)
2. The product series ("P-26", "D-25-A",  "26-A-C", etc)
3. The warehouse where the product is stored ("P1", "D4", "A3", etc)
4. The shelf number where the product is stored ("1", "17", "25", etc)
5. The number of units within each box

There is quite a mess with the stock, and I need to rearrange some of it.
The problem is that the stock is dynamic, and I need my lists to be dynamic also.

My end goal is to list all the boxes with less than X items in the box and match all similar products (similar product = has the same name and series), and where exactly it's located (warehouse and shelf).

I've succeeded in creating the dynamic list of lacking boxes using The QUERY function, and also in creating a formula for the second part (matching all similar products, and their location).

The problem is it's a drag-down formula, and I need a dynamic formula, based on the size of the former list.

The first list is pretty much straight forward:

```
=Arrayformula(Concat(QUERY('Tiles_stock'!$A$4:AC$216,"Select A  Where R < 0.13"),(Concat("_",QUERY('Tiles_stock'!$A$4:AC$216,"Select C  Where R < 0.13")))))
```

The formula returns the warehouse and the shelf, matched together.

Now the tricky part, the second formula is:

```
=Textjoin(" , ",True, Arrayformula(Concat(QUERY('Tiles_stock'!$A$4:X$216,"Select A  where N contains '"& O4 &"' AND O contains '"& P4 &"' AND R > 0.13 "),(Concat("_",QUERY('Tiles_stock'!$A$4:X$216,"Select C  where N contains '"& O4 &"' AND O contains '"& P4 &"' AND R > 0.13 "))))))
```

Which works fine, but forces me to drag it down or up each time the first list has changed (as I said, it's a stock, and it's dynamic).

Here's an image of what I'm basically trying to achieve:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UIim9oFRyOqYZpzcg9VsYvzuffP6sQ7F/view?usp=sharing

Here's a link to the spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13q7EBz18z6t_iMVTT-M7fzcPjtdYligYjz_m90h_z3A/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

> list all the boxes with less than X items in the box and match all similar products (similar product = has the same name and series)...

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({QUERY(
 QUERY(QUERY({A2:A&" "&B2:B, C2:C&"_"&D2:D, E2:E}, 
 "select Col1,Col2 where Col3 >= 10", 0), 
 "select Col1, count(Col1) group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0), 
 "select Col1", 0), 
 REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(ISNUMBER(
 QUERY(QUERY({A2:A&" "&B2:B, C2:C&"_"&D2:D, E2:E}, 
 "select Col1,Col2 where Col3 >= 10", 0), 
 "select count(Col1) group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0)), 
 QUERY(QUERY({A2:A&" "&B2:B, C2:C&"_"&D2:D, E2:E}, 
 "select Col1,Col2 where Col3 >= 10", 0), 
 "select count(Col1) group by Col1 pivot Col2 limit 0", 0)&",", )),,999^99))), ",$", )}, 
 "offset 1", 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hi player0, I tried to embed your formula in the spreadsheet mentioned above, but it yielded nothing. could you note what I've missed ?

Comment: well I can provide you with my sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jb3XsLAiGVpgXhZQh76pr2HR42SX8eQZ-JvRdVbKDPg/copy